# Analytic varieties for the primes and the twin primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, prime-numbers

I am wondering what real and complex analysis say
about the primes and twin primes.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_variety)

> analytic variety is defined locally as the set of common zeros of finitely many analytic functions

Let

$$ P(x) = \sin^2(\pi x) + \sin^2( \frac{\pi \cdot (\Gamma(x)+1)}{ x})$$

The real roots of $P(x)$ greater than one are exactly the primes.
Since it is a sum of squares, both terms must vanish.
$\sin(\pi x)$ vanishes at integers and the second term
is Wilson's primality test.

Let $P_2(x) = P(x)^2 + P(x+2)^2$.

The real roots of $P_2(x)$ greater than one are exactly the smaller twin of
twin primes.

I believe $P(x)$ is of no practical interest since
$\Gamma(x)$ grows prohibitively fast.

> Q1 Are there computationally better real functions with
> zeros exactly the primes?

Prime (resp. twin prime) counting is counting the zeros
of $P(x)$ (resp. $P_2(x)$).

> Q2 Does analysis give bounds for the number of zeros in an interval?
>
> Q3 Are some properties of the complex roots of $P(x)$ known?

The complex XRays look messy to me.

The primes appear to be zeros of multiplicity $2$.

Plot:

[image]